# How do I pass an android object from a destroyed activity?

Tags: android, object, action, bundle, menuitem

This seems to be a crazily hard challenge for such a simple problem!

- I have a MenuItem that has an Icon in my android app.
- The MenuItem's container is an Action Bar (appcompat version)
- I have the reference to ActionBar
- The user can change the icon to the MenuItem.
- I use a boolean to track the current status of the icon (it can only be 1 of 2 icons)
- When the view is changed from
  portrait to landscape (or vice versa), they activity is destroyed,
  taking all variables etc with it.

3 Failed solutions:

1. Normally, I would solve this problem by using Bundle. However,
   Bundle accepts only primitives and parcelables. How can I parcel a
   MenuItem (if at all)?
2. An alternative, would be to grab the MenuItem in the new activity
       and use the boolean mentioned above to decide the icon value.
       However, there appears to be no way to grab a MenuItem without it
       first being pressed (i.e. this.getMenu()).
3. Another alternative would be to simulate pressing the MenuItem
       depending on the boolean value. However, there appears to be no way
       to simulate pressing a MenuItem (mainly because there is no way to
       grab a MenuItem!).

How can I change the logo of the MenuItem on the Action Bar on the new activity when the orientation changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1、save the state of a boolean value when the Activity onSaveInstanceState

2、restore the boolean value when the activity re-onCreate.

3、Change the icon when the Menu creating.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
        if(mIsTrue){
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.true_icon);
        }else{
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.false_icon);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this code makes the assumption that the MenuItem you are changing is in the index 0, which is not necessarily true. You will most likely want to get the MenuItem you want using its id, i.e. `MenuItem item = menu.getItem(R.id.your_menu_item);`, where the id is declared in your `menu/main.xml`

Comment: @btse if you want find the menuItem with id, you should use the API menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_id). the Menu.getItem(index) API is for the indexing.

Comment: @Changewei Yao oh yup you are correct. Doesn't my initial idea still hold truth though?

Comment: Massive thanks to Yao. Frankly, I could kiss you! So simple!! Thanks to BTSE for the tip too. I updated my code to your idea as it seems more solid and elegant. Solved :)